# Найти ближайшее число в массиве, если расстояние одинаковое вывести левое

Tags: javascript

Данный код, не проходит этот тест 
nearestValue([0,-2],-1) должно вывести -2, а выводит 0.

Тесты в этих массивах проходит.

```
nearestValue([4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17], 100), 17);
nearestValue([5, 10, 8, 12, 89, 100], 7), 8);
nearestValue([-1, 2, 3], 0), -1);
```

Как можно реализовать, чтобы когда расстояние между значениями одинаковое выводило наименьшее?

```
function nearestValue(values: number[], search: number): number {
  let countValue = values.length;
  let nearest = values[0];
  for (let i = 0; i <= countValue; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(nearest - search) > Math.abs(values[i] - search)) {
      nearest = values[i];
    }
  }
  return nearest;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function nearestValue(arr, val) {
  return arr.reduce((nearest, num) => Math.abs(num - val) >= Math.abs(nearest - val) && nearest < num? nearest : num);
}

console.log(nearestValue([0,-2],-1))
console.log(nearestValue([4, 7, 10, 11, 12, 17], 100));
console.log(nearestValue([5, 10, 8, 12, 89, 100], 7));
console.log(nearestValue([-1, 2, 3], 0));
```